# WPF - ComboBox SelectedItem not binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, combobox

I have a two views : One in which I have a list of bills and the second one that has a form to add/edit bills.

The  BillView contains some textboxes and a combobox to fill in.
Problem is  if I try to edit a bill  when the BillView opens the textboxes are displaing the values I entered when adding a bill except the combobox that is not showing the value I selected when adding the bill(but the list binding is alright). Used a breakpoint on the BillAccount set and it seems its working but the the comboxbox selecteditem is not set.

The BillView(used to add/edit bills) :

```
<Label Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Account" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="5"  ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}" DisplayMemberPath="TheAccount.AccountName" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding BillAccount}"/>
```

This is the constructor of the BillViewModel:

```
public BillViewModel(BillModel bill)
   {   
       BillId = bill.TheBill.BillId;
       AccountId = bill.TheBill.AccountId;
       BillAmmount = (double)bill.TheBill.Ammount;
       NextDate = bill.TheBill.NextDate;
       this.accounts = GetAccounts(); // populates the list
       billAccount = accounts.Where(i => i.TheAccount.AccountId == this.AccountId).First();
   }


 public AccountModel BillAccount 
    {
        get { return billAccount; }
        set { billAccount = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("BillAccount");
        }
    }
```

The GetAccounts() method:

```
private ObservableCollection<AccountModel> GetAccounts()
    {
        if (accounts == null)
            accounts = new ObservableCollection<AccountModel>();
        accounts.Clear();

        using(var context = new Ents())
        {
            foreach(var account in context.Accounts)
            {
                accounts.Add(new AccountModel() { TheAccount = account });
            }
        }
        return accounts;
    }
```

The method should be fine.

Comment: Can you look at your output window to see if there are any binding issues reported?

Comment: Just to be sure : `Accounts` is a proprerty that simply exposes the `accounts` field ?

Comment: Also, you're using DisplayMemberPath as well... does your AccountModel object have a "TheAccount" property?  And does that object have a "AccountName" property?

Comment: No binding errors. @Russ yes, the AccountModel has a property called TheAccount and TheAccount has several properties including AccountName.

Comment: Could you please try to remove the use of the DisplayMemberPath and see if the ComboBox displays the ToString() of the BillAccount property's value?

Comment: I removed it and behaves like before except displaying the ToString() value instead of the AccountName.

Comment: Ah, sorry, Christian... I was taking us down the wrong path here... I was confusing the UI w/ something else... obviously the DisplayMemberPath is working correctly, and it's not the issue if each item in the list is displaying correctly.

Comment: In order for the ItemsSource/SelectedItem pattern works correctly, the exact same instances of Items should be used everywhere. You're going to the Context to get these instances, which may or may not return the same instances (I dunno lol). if I were you, I'd pass the collection of AccountModels to use down into the BillAccount constructor.  This ensures the same instances are used everywhere in the UI.

Comment: I'm thinking this is a reference value comparison issue.  Please take a look at this post [link](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/comboboxs-selecteditem-not-displaying/)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help and time. In the end it worked after I cleaned/rebuild/referenced everything again. Still don't know what the problem was but I'm glad it is working.

Answer (score 0):

bill account is variable not property --

```
billAccount = accounts.Where(i => i.TheAccount.AccountId == this.AccountId).First();
```

change to

```
BillAccount = accounts.Where(i => i.TheAccount.AccountId == this.AccountId).First();
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the issue, as

BillAccount = accounts.Where(i => i.TheAccount.AccountId == this.AccountId).First();

is happening in the constructor, which will have executed before the binding has been completed to the view.

Comment: well property change is not fired unless you update your property.. try that

Comment: its not property in constructor ... use 'B'

Comment: PropertyChanged doesn't have to fire at the time he's setting it... everything in the constructor has already executed by the time the view is bound to the viewmodel.  At the time the code in the constructor is executing, binding isn't even set up, yet.

Comment: Did you try to set your SelectedItem via code? Give your comboBox a name, set the selectedItem to an actual item and check if that is working.

Comment: Same goes for `Accounts` set the Property not the backing field, because else PropertyChanges never gets raised